# what is the meaning of 'if form holds'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

***If form holds***, the 250,000 women each year who undergo the same genetic testing Jolie had will be joined by the thousands more; but the mutation that was detected in her, in what's known as BRCA1 gene, is ~~.

Answer (score 3):

"If the trend continues":

[Dictionary:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/form)

> manner, method, or style of doing something, esp with regard to recognized standards

Comment: The most common idiom in US is "true to form" http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/true+to+form

Comment: Yeah, that was what I went for. I have never heard of "if form holds" However it is from a senior editor at Time mag: http://healthland.time.com/author/jkluger/ - seems to be more of a sports expression

Answer (score 0):

"If the pattern holds..."   Although when I read it out of context I thought it meant:   "If propriety holds..."